Fix ruby project inconsistent files using zeitwerk
For a large (non-Rails) ruby project with thousands files not following naming convention for class, module and constants that uses a lot require and require_relative and potential circular dependency, is there a way to detect them so that corrective action could be apply and allow adopting the code loader?
I have found something for Rails project
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/railties/lib/rails/zeitwerk_checker.rb

Easiest solution in my opinion would be to simply view the files and rename and reorganize them into a conventional structure that zietwerk likes. As for "circular dependency" that's not necessarily a thing. require will check to see if the file has already been loaded and if so it will return false this process has very little overhead, so this is of far less concern than "ruby project with thousands files not following naming convention"

It's like 10k+ files, not sure I can easily review it 1 by 1.

The require and require_relative calls are not important in the sense that if you migrate, they would be removed.
One way to approach this would be to eager load the project, iterate over ObjectSpace to print const_source_location of class and modules whose path lives in the project.
Then, in a temporary script not yet driving the project, instantiate a Zeitwerk loader, set its root directory or directories, and then check loader.all_expected_cpaths. This method gives you the constant paths expected in the project with the given configuration, and it does not load the code. So you can run this even if the project is not managed by Zeitwerk.
Those two sources of data can be compared and could give you one metric.
To make both of them converge, you will generally move things around. You can do this while staying in your project. Just move the files, put one thing in one file, and revise the require and require_relative calls so that the project still works (assuming those are not public interface and you can change locations).
When that is re-organized, you can either rename constants if needed, or use inflections to leave them as they are.

Good suggestions. Do you happen to have a draft script or intended to support this feature in zeitwerk?

One way to approach this would be to eager load the project

How to do this properly for 10k+ ruby files?

@xtremeHitori provided that all of your files appropriately require dependent files a quick and dirty approach would be Dir.glob('your_project_root/**/*.rb') {|f| require f}. That being said based on your description its seems like you lack of autoloading at the moment, this leads me to believe you have some kind of entry point for the project that already chain requires every file.

Regarding support from Zeitwerk, migrating a project is too ad-hoc to be automated, all_expected_cpaths is the part Zeitwerk can help with.
